# String split to remove everything after _

Tags: r, split

I have a list of file names [image] and want to string extract just the part of the name before the _ [image]

I tried using the following but was unsuccessful.

```
condition <- strsplit(count_files, "_*")
```

also tried

```
condition <- strsplit(count_files, "_*.[c,t]sv")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(count_files, whitespace = "_.*")
[1] "Fibroblast" "Fibroblast"
```

---

The output from `strsplit` is a `list`, it may need to be `unlist`ed.  Also, when we use `_*` the regex mentioned is zero or more `_`.  Instead, it should be `_.*` i.e. `_` followed by zero or more other characters (`.*`)

```
unlist(strsplit(count_files, "_.*"))
```

#### data

```
count_files <- c("Fibroblast_1.csv", "Fibroblast_2.csv")
```